# plot same entries intro different bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

The ggplot R code below will plot a barplot where `NA` entries are automatically combined into the same bar. Is it possible to plot them as separate bars? Thanks

```
df<-cbind.data.frame("Spp"=c("calb",NA,NA,"cglab"),
                     "col"=c("black","red","blue","green"),
                     "N"=c(10,20,30,40))
df$col <- factor(df$col, levels = c("black","red","blue","green"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Spp, y=N, fill=col)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=N),size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = as.character(df$col))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this...I hope I got you correct

```
df<-cbind.data.frame("Spp"=c("calb",NA,NA,"cglab"),
                     "col"=c("black","red","blue","green"),
                     "N"=c(10,20,30,40))
df$col <- factor(df$col, levels = c("black","red","blue","green"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=col, y=N, fill=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=N),size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = as.character(df$col))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=df$Spp)
```

[image]

Comment: great. glad it's what you need :)